# Creating Sequence in PostgreSQL using start with nextval('old_seq')

Tags: postgresql

I would like to make a script in PostgreSQL to create a sequence for a table. I would like to put maximum value of another sequence as a min value of this new one. I'm trying to do this like:

```
create sequence test
INCREMENT 1
MINVALUE SELECT max (id) from test_table
```

Also I've tried:

```
create sequence test
INCREMENT 1
MINVALUE SELECT nextval('old_seq')
```

Is it even possible to do this at the point of creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setval()` after creating the sequence:

```
create sequence test INCREMENT 1;
select setval('test', nextval('old_seq'));
```